# What's the difference between += and =+ in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've heard `=+` is the same as `a = a + b`, and `+=` is like "add `a` to `b` and return `a`" or something of that sort, but it's really confusing me how similar the two are. Could someone could explain the difference to me?

Comment: `=+` isn't one operator. It's the normal assignment operator followed by unary plus. `a =+ b` is the same as `a = +b`, which is the same as `a = b` unless `b` has a weirdly overloaded unary `+` operator.

Comment: The confusion at the base of this question is a pretty good argument for using whitespace around operators, even when the language doesn't strictly require it. Instead of `a=b*3+1` write `a = b * 3 + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the difference between `+=` and `=+` in ruby?

This question is non-sensical, since there is no such thing as `=+` in Ruby. It doesn't make sense to ask about the difference between two things when one of those two things doesn't exist.

The only sensible difference between `+=` and `=+` in Ruby is that `+=` exists and `=+` doesn't.

Comment: Oh wow, well that's good to know. I'm just breaking into ruby, and I was learning += and thought I saw =+ and couldn't find the difference on google or anywhere, in relation to ruby anyway.. this explains it. Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator like `=+` in ruby. If you are doing `a =+ 1` when the value of a is 1. it always returns 1. but, if you are doing `a += 1` it will return 2. you can't increment/decrement with `=+`.